# Calling a function within a array

Tags: jquery, arrays

How do I go about calling a function within a jQuery array to add another array?

```
$('#map').zoommap({

        // Width and Height of the Map
        width: '490px',
        height: '380px',

        //Region
        map: function getMaps();

    });
```

getMaps() should return the following:

```
{
    id: 'campus',
    image: '/resources/images/maps/'+mapId,
    data: '',
    maps: []
}
```

Cheers,
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure

```
map: getMaps()
```

Will do the trick. No `;` at the end (just a comma if you need to add more items), and you don't need to put `function` before it either, unless you're trying to declare a function.

If you're questioning how to write the `getMaps()` function, you pretty much have that too..

```
function getMaps() {
    return {
        id: 'campus',
        image: '/resources/images/maps/'+mapId,
        data: '',
        maps: []
    }
}
```

Although I don't know why you need the function at all, when you could just put the inner `{ id: ... }` right in it's place.... putting it all together:

```
$('#map').zoommap({
    // Width and Height of the Map
    width: '490px',
    height: '380px',

    //Region
    map: {
        id: 'campus',
        image: '/resources/images/maps/'+mapId,
        data: '',
        maps: []
    }
});
```

Comment: That should do it.
The reason for the function is because I'm going to eventually get the array via an ajax call.

Comment: Fair enough :) I prefer to call it a "dict" though, so as not to be confused with an actual `[]` array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#map').zoommap({

        // Width and Height of the Map
        width: '490px',
        height: '380px',

        //Region
        map: getMaps()

    });
```